# How to move one subfigure up so that it matches my left subfigure?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

[image]

How can I move my second subfigure up so that it matches my left figure? Currently I have:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics[width=4in,height=3in,keepaspectratio]{DT}
  \includegraphics[width=4in,height=3in,keepaspectratio]{randomforests}
\end{figure}
```

I've seen some other solutions using `minipage` and `subfigure`, but I want to keep the a and b the way they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your sub-figure labels are embedded inside the graphics. As such, there's no need for a sub-figure package to manage the labels. Instead, load the [`adjustbox` package](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) with the `export` option and add `vadjust=t` to your `\includegraphics` options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics
    [width=2in,height=2in,keepaspectratio,valign=t]{example-image-golden-upright}
  \includegraphics
    [width=2in,height=2in,keepaspectratio,valign=t]{example-image}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, cheers!